# Problemas com identação no HTML usando o Prettier no VSC?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Alguém sabe me dizer porque a indentação do `Prettier` *(extensão do VSC*) não está funcionando em arquivo HTML, configurei pra indentar com 4 espaços, funciona no `CSS` e no `JS`, mas não funciona no `HTML`.

Como eu posso resolver isso?

CSS - ok

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

JS - ok

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML - não

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Config do Prettier

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei marcar e desmarcar o `checkBox`, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolvido**

O problema era q tinha vários padrões de formatação disponíveis para fazer a indentação instalados no meu VSC, e ele não conseguia escolher um. Apertei `ctrl + shift + F` (no arquivo HTML), então o VSC mandou escolher um dos tipos de formatação disponível, escolhi o Prettier e a partir dai ele começou a fazer a formatação do HTML usando o Prettier automaticamente (ao salvar). Fica ai a solução caso alguém esteja com o mesmo problema.